# How to disable specific hours in Angular Igx Time Picker Component?

Tags: angular, date, time, datetimepicker, timepicker

I am using [Angular Igx Time Picker](https://www.infragistics.com/products/ignite-ui-angular/angular/components/time-picker) and I am trying to disable some specific hours in some specific dates. For example, I want to disable the range from 10:00 to 12:00 in 10/02/2024 and range 15:00 to 17:00 in 17/02/2024.

So far I can define a max and min hour but not a specific range within the displayed hours.

How can this be achieved?

Here is my code:

```
<igx-time-picker formControlName="time" [itemsDelta]="{hours:1, minutes:15}" [inputFormat]="'H:mm'" [minValue]="09:00:00" [maxValue]="18:00:00"></igx-time-picker>
```

I have looked up in the references but cannot find any attribute to do so. Could it be done in any other way in the TS component?